# How to step into VB.NET class code

Tags: vb.net

I am debugging a VB.NET forms program which calls into properties and methods of a class which is part of the same project.

I put a break point in the form code but when I step through, it does not step into the class code.

Am I missing a setting?

Comment: have you tried rebuilding your project?

Answer (score 3):

Pressing F11 will take you into the method definition. F10 will step over. F5 will jump to the next break point. Or simply continue with the execution of your application until the application meets another break point on it's execution path.

This can can also be achieved by using actions located on the toolbar and in the context menu when using right click.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are pressing Step Into, not Step Over.

Comment: It does seem to step into the method code, but does not step into the properties code. I'm sure I have seen debugging step into properties code before in previous projects.